# Bootstrap: How to make panels auto collapse when clicking on another panel?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

In Bootstrap how do I make panels auto-collapse when clicking another one so that only one panel is open at a time? I'm not very good at JavaScript.

Here is some sample code:

```
<div class="footer-widget-panel panel-group" id="accordion1">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading"><h4 class="panel-title"><a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#infoPanel">Information</a></h4>
    </div>
    <div id="panell" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
      Panel 1
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="footer-widget-panel panel-group" id="accordion2">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading"><h4 class="panel-title"><a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#infoPanel">Information</a></h4>
    </div>
    <div id="panel2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
      Panel 2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="footer-widget-panel panel-group" id="accordion3">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading"><h4 class="panel-title"><a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion3" href="#infoPanel">Information</a></h4>
    </div>
    <div id="panel3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
      Panel 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you got the concept of Bootstrap's accordion wrong: You now have three individual accordions each holding one panel (#accordion1, #accordion2, #accordion3). If you want other panels to collapse when you click on one of them, they should all belong to the same parent accordion (referred to by the data-parent attribute). Also, be sure to use all necessary aria- and data- attributes, and refer to the correct heading / panel child IDs. For example:

```
<div class="footer-widget-panel panel-group" id="accordion1" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#panel1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="panel1">Information</a></h4>
    </div>
    <div id="panel1" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="panel-body">
      Panel 1
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#panel2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="panel2">Information</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="panel2" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
      <div class="panel-body">
      Panel 2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#panel3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="panel3">Information</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="panel3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
      Panel 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x2bph14h/

Answer (score 1):

Because you have three different accordions a solution in pure javascript according to your question tag is:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[id^=accordion]').forEach(function(ele, idx) {
    ele.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        var currTarget = this.querySelector('.panel-collapse.collapse');
        document.querySelectorAll('[id^=accordion] .panel-collcollapse').forEach(function(ele, idx) {
            if (ele != currTarget) {
                ele.classList.remove('in');
                ele.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'false');
            }
        })
    });
})
```

while a simple solution in jQuery is:

```
$('[id^=accordion]').on('show.bs.collapse', function (e) {
    $('[id^=accordion] .panel-collapse.collapse').not(e.target).collapse('hide');
});
```

The snippet:

```js
/**
$('[id^=accordion]').on('show.bs.collapse', function (e) {
    $('[id^=accordion] .panel-collapse.collapse').not(e.target).collapse('hide');
});
**/

document.querySelectorAll('[id^=accordion]').forEach(function(ele, idx) {
    ele.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        var currTarget = this.querySelector('.panel-collapse.collapse');
        document.querySelectorAll('[id^=accordion] .panel-collapse.collapse').forEach(function(ele, idx) {
            if (ele != currTarget) {
                ele.classList.remove('in');
                ele.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'false');
            }
        })
    });
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="footer-widget-panel panel-group" id="accordion1">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading"><h4 class="panel-title"><a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#infoPanel1">Information</a></h4>
        </div>
        <div id="infoPanel1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                Panel 1
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="footer-widget-panel panel-group" id="accordion2">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading"><h4 class="panel-title"><a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#infoPanel2">Information</a></h4>
        </div>
        <div id="infoPanel2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                Panel 2
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="footer-widget-panel panel-group" id="accordion3">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading"><h4 class="panel-title"><a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion3" href="#infoPanel3">Information</a></h4>
        </div>
        <div id="infoPanel3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                Panel 3
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes you are using Bootstrap 3.

What you'd have to do is put all your panels under one common wrapper, referenced by some id. Then you'd put this id into the `data-parent` attribute of the `<a>` tags used to open and close the panels. Also, your HTML included some mistakes, such as the `href` attribute of the `<a>` tags not containing the ID of the panels they should control (`infoPanel` instead of `panel1`) and the `<a>` tags having the `collapsed` class for some reason.

Here is a JSFiddle based on your code: [Click](https://jsfiddle.net/tudtrqp0/). The important part is the `#collapse-group` wrapper along with the `data-parent` attributes. More on that in the [Bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse%20%22Bootstrap%20documentation%20on%20collapse)